# How to run CodedUI Tests using TFS 2013 and VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am trying set up Coded User Interface Test running without Visual Studio on remote machine
I have already installed Test Controller(Visual Studio 2012) and Test Agent(Visual Studio 2012) on Visual Studio Server 2012

But while I am trying to Build Definition using Team Foundation Server 2013

I got the following error

File not found: 'MSTest.exe'

Project was compiled on Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: What build process template are you using? If I had to wager a guess, it would be that there's something hard-coded somewhere to use the VS2013 version of MSTest, which is in a different folder than VS2012. It might be worth it to install the VS2013 test agent.

Comment: I am using Default Template.11.1.xaml

Comment: I can not install VS2013 version of MSTest. Is there any other way to resolve this?

Comment: I have configured everything , but the error is the same: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s). File not found: MSTest.exe

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TFS 2013 you must have the Test Controller and Agent from the 2013 agents disk. Don't worry, you will still be able to build and execute tests from VS2012.

Comment: Done. Do i need test settings file? Do I need to connect to Team project collection on controller i tried with test settings file and without it nothing help the error is the same. Where does it look for 'MSTest.exe' file?

Comment: No - You need to configure everything, including the test settings in MTM. yes- your test controller needs to be registered with TFS. not sure- it should just all work with just the TFS 2013 Test Agent installed.